# How to publish asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, web, publish

I have created a web site in asp.net with sql database. I want to publish it. I searched on google but it is showing me to publish site on iis. But I want to publish it online like www.mysite.com.

How can i publish my asp.net website like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET applications can be only hosted in IIS Server.
So you need a web server to publish your website.
Then you need to purchase a domain name like "www.mysite.com" from any vendors.
Then you can easily map the purchased domain to your published site in IIS.

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

i found this on the with a quick search:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWLCZukjPz0